# Strange header: Warning 218

Tags: http-headers

Last  time in my company we checked the headers that web servers sent to our computers. One of these computers received **Warning 218 'Transformation applied'** header from many different servers. Other computers have not recieived it. What does it mean?

Comment: Is that a typo?  I'm assuming you're referring to the Warning header in HTTP and that you actually got a 214 code as per:  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.46.  That right?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-ct-guidelines-20080414/, the 'transformation applied' header means there is a proxy server that changed headers.
That same proxy server *should* also send the original header, prefixed with `X-Device-`.

So, it looks like there is a proxy between the client and the internet, and that proxy is changing some of the HTTP headers. If the proxy is doing its job properly, you should be able to see what headers, too.